# Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to [[xx.xxx.xx.xx]:10050]: [4] Interrupted system call

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, zabbix

Getting this error on my Zabbix Server web. I have my server on a VM and the agent is running on the Kubernetes (GKE).  The following image is the status of Zabbix agent. [image]

Comment: is there something useful inside the zabbix agent log?

Comment: Its showing 


agent #3 started [listener #2]
 
agent #2 started [listener #1]
 
agent #1 started [collector]
 
agent #0 started [main process]
 
loaded modules: zabbix_module_docker.so, zabbix_module_stress.so, zabbix_module_systemd.so, zabbix_module_sockets.so
 
using configuration file: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

Comment: it looks like you are using zabbix in passive mode. Have you been checking if port 10050 is accessible from outside? Have you tried zabbix in active mode?

Comment: Good catch Nick. Indeed if the agent is inside the K8s, it's likely unreachable from Zabbix Server, because of the natting.

Answer (score 1):

Can telnet ZabbixSeverIP  10050  from agent?, if not then need to open port from agentServer to Zabbixserver.

and in /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf , need to add Zabbixserver Ipaddress and LocalHostname as well